# Python - Tornado - How to write unit test for independent functions?

Tags: python-2.7, tornado

I have a handler (subclass of RequestHandler) which handles GET, POST, PUT and DELETE requests. The class also has independent functions which operates on DB. I am writing unit test for the class, but I am not able to initialize the class since it requires 2 arguments. How can I do it?

Note: I don't have issues while testing rest calls.

Comment: Can you show your solution?

Comment: @viakondratiuk
class TestRestClass1(unittest.TestCase, RestClassHandler):

where RestClassHandler is the class to be tested. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by making my testcase class a subclass of the class under testing.

Answer (score 0):

The two arguments are the `tornado.web.Application` and the `tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest`. Normally, rather than constructing a `RequestHandler` directly, Tornado applications are tested via `tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase` which will create the handlers as needed. (You could construct the `application` and `request` by hand, but I wouldn't recommend it)

Do the functions you want to test need the `application` or `request` objects? If not, you could move them out of the subclass of `RequestHandler` to test them in isolation. If they do need either of these objects, then `AsyncHTTPTestCase` is the simplest way to get them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ben. Yes the methods could be isolated, but I wanted to know if we could do it without it. Finally got it done by subclassing the testcase class!!